# Why do I see 240v between hot and neutral when one breaker is out in my mobile home?

Tags: electrical

This is an a double wide mobile home. The two sides of the kitchen are on different circuits. When both Breakers are on one side reads 120 hot to ground 120 neutral to ground 240 something hot to neutral. When just one breaker is on it reads 120v hot to ground nothing anywhere else

Comment: It sounds like either the service lost its neutral, or the kitchen is served by an MWBC and the MWBC lost its neutral.  Check other voltages all over the house.   If yet other circuits are wrong, **call the power company and report an outage NOW**.  Otherwise carefully review the kitchen circuit.

Comment: I had the power company out to make sure everything was okay to the meter and it was. At the service panel when I measure across both hots I get 249 but from neutral to either Hot Side I get 10 or so

Answer (score 1):

Neutral to ground should not be 120.  It should be at (or very near) 0.  Neutral and ground are generally bonded at the service panel.  When only one breaker being on causes this (and the other doesn't), it seems unlikely that you have lost your neutral service from the supplier.  There is likely a fault on the neutral associated with one of the circuits.  It's also possible that there is a faulty or mis-wired MWBC (explanation of MWBC [here](http://www.ahouseonarock.com/midlothian-home-inspector/what-is-an-mwbc/)).

You could try disconnecting the wires from the breakers in the service panel and testing directly from the breaker to the neutral and ground.  If everything tests as expected, you're looking at a wire fault.  Otherwise, the wire isn't the first problem to fix.

Comment: It would be enough if the MWBC were grandfathered (combined with recent work).  Only recently (2005?) they required you *pigtail* neutrals on MWBCs (the way you pigtail grounds).  Same reason: so you can remove a device without severing neutral.  If this was installed pre-rule, it's more likely to have a problem.